# VIN Barcode Scanner SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios, vin

I am searching for a  VIN  (vehicle identification number) barcode  SDK. Has any1 implemented then please help me with some tutorials ans sample codes. I din't find anything helpful.All i found is barcode reader but not VIN.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: The zbar barcode library can handle VIN bar codes.

Comment: @rmaddy i have tired that but its not supporting VIN

Comment: I've scanned the VIN on my own car with my own app using zbar. What iOS device did you use? It does require one with autofocus.

Comment: ios 6.0 and what does autofocus means?

Comment: I asked what device you used, not what version of iOS. And by autofocus, I'm talking about the camera.

Comment: oh sorry its ipad 2 and no autofocusing

Comment: The camera on the iPad 2 is terrible. It hardly works at all with zbar. With an iPhone 4 or better, zbar will scan VIN codes.

Comment: Yes you are right the same code works for iphone n not for ipad. Any solution to this.

Comment: It should work with all other iPads, just not the iPad 2.

Comment: so it will just work with ipad 3

Comment: Hi Dhara : did you find any free VIN scanner SDK ?? am also looking for the same . can you please share if you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some libraries available for this.

Please check these links for sdk's and demo apps:

1. [**bees4honey**](https://github.com/bees4honey/mobile_vin_scanner)
2. [**fastbook**](http://www.fastbook.com/)

Comment: hey thanks for the references but this paid version. Do you know any free sdk available?

Comment: @Dhara: No, I'll check, if I get any, I'll update my answer

Comment: Hi , did you find any free SDK until now ?

Comment: @wod: no dude. Till now I didn't get any. If you know any sdk, please let me know.

Answer (score 8):

I know this has been answered already, but...

VIN's are just Code 39 Barcodes.

You can use: http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx to read the barcode and then use http://developer.edmunds.com/ to decipher the vehicle information.  This is the best no cost solution I've been able to come up with.

Comment: The problem with Vin codes is that they are irregularly shaped for Code 39 barcodes. I have tried multiple times using the zxing libraries, and their sample app doesn't work with vins on any device I've tried.

Comment: @K.Niemczyk : That is completely untrue. The reason some of the open source libraries often dont work is because of resolution issues, as the vin codes from bar 39 are quite long, often the default configurations are not compatible... Check out my answer for a free solution that works with a completely free open source library.

Comment: @Jeremie Been a while since I looked at this. If I recall correctly, at the time, I couldn't get the zxing libraries to work with the Android device I was using, even after making some changes to try and deal with the resolution problem (Unfortunately, I don't think I still have that code). Also, when I couldn't get zxing's base app to read VINs on any device I tried it on (couple different ios devices, and an android tablet). As such, I didn't have a lot of confidence in trying to use it. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 5):

ZBar reads Code 39 Barcodes. Its free and open source. See my answer here for working [source code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20954929/783198)

***Edit/Note:the iOS framework now includes a barcode scanner as of iOS 7. I used [this implementation](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx) to get better and easier results than using Zbar.***

[Free SDK for scanning barcode (code 39 format) in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340418/free-sdk-for-scanning-barcode-code-39-format-in-ios/20954929#20954929)

Comment: This solution is completely free and works flawlessly for me

Answer (score 1):

We can use AVFoundation to scan following types of barcode in ios.

The framework reads the below barcodes:

2D Barcodes:

1. QR
2. PDF417
3. Aztec

1D Barcodes:

1. Code 128
2. EAN-8
3. EAN-13
4. UPC-A
5. UPC-E
6. Code 39
7. Code 93

Since VIN is a code 39 barcode we get it done very easily without using any third party library.